Right click in Files has inconsistent behavior. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't?
Versions

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
GNOME nautilus 46.2

Behavior
When I try and use my right-click context menu options in Nautilus/Files, it only sometimes works. I have more luck if I try more slowly, but that's no guarantee either.
Video Showing Behavior
Note: this has only been happening since my migration from Ubuntu 22.XX to 24.XX.

This is a known issue in GTK with X11 that has no fix yet other than switching to Wayland.
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/5923
